# Rewrite para borrar el ID de una url en wordpress

Tags: regex, nginx

Tengo algunos direcciones indexadas con el formato ID-slug, y quería crear una regla para nginx que eliminara el ID

```
https://misitio.es/12-titulo-del-post-uno
https://misitio.es/45-titulo-del-post-dos
https://misitio.es/56-titulo-del-post-n
```

pasarlo a

```
https://misitio.es/titulo-del-post-uno
https://misitio.es/titulo-del-post-dos
https://misitio.es/titulo-del-post-n
```

He probado varios regex, y pese a que el [regex me da valido](http://rubular.com/r/pp4pjDZAac), nginx no hace nada.

```
rewrite ^([0-9]+)-(.+)$ $2 permanent;
```

Otro

```
rewrite ^([0-9]+)-(.+)$ $2 last;
```

Otro

```
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)-(.+)$ /$2 last;
```

Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Son muchas direcciones las que se encuentran indexadas así? Lo digo porque en el caso de que no sea inviable poner cada una de ellas manualmente, te ahorrarías el problema de que te re-escriba url's que un futuro podrían ser válidas (que empiecen por un número) como pudiera ser, en el caso de que escribieras noticias, "2 hombres atracan un banco".

Comment: Bien, podria hacerlo asi, son unas 100. En cualquier caso un ID de wordpres es un campo (y si migro a otro soft es un formato comun). El planteamiento fue que inicialmente pense que era bueno tener el id en el slug, pero luego vi que no es asi, y que mejor que el slug no tenga ese id. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: ¿No te arriesgas a que en algún momento aparezcan posts con títulos repetidos?

Comment: Wordpress o el app que estoy haciendo no me lo permtirian pues para eso el slug o url corta es un campo con undice unico. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Después de unas prueba encontré la que creo la mejor solución.

```
location ~ /([0-9]+)-(.+) {
   return   301 https://$server_name/$2;
}
```